# saving the data at the end of every time a loop runs

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, loops

I have an array (100,4) in python. I want to save it in 9 different arrays in text files. The order of resultant arrays is as follows: 2nd & 4th having (15,4) shape & rest of the arrays will have (10,4) shape. Please check the code below & recommend corrections. I have difficulty in writing the 2nd & 4th arrays specifically.

```
import numpy as np

m001=np.loadtxt('C:/hbp001.txt',skiprows=6) # array
m001=np.reshape(m001,(10,10,4))
for year in range (9):
        pre=np.reshape((m001[0:10,:,:]),(29565,99))
        np.savetxt('C:/year1.txt')
```

Comment: Have you read the `savetxt` docs?

Comment: I have solved the issue. Thanks